# How do I transform a large, often-used C++ macro with trivial per-use changes into a C++ template or similar?

Tags: c++, templates, insert, macros, code-duplication

I'm working on a container, which has code similar to the following pseudocode:

```
#define LARGE_INSERT_MACRO (ASSIGNMENT_OBJECT) \
if (some_stuff) \
{ \
    ... do more stuff ... \
    allocator.construct(place_to_insert_to, ASSIGNMENT_OBJECT); \
    ... etc ... \
} \
else if (other_stuff) \
{ \
    ... do different stuff ...  \
    allocator.construct(place_to_insert_to, ASSIGNMENT_OBJECT); \
    ... etc ... \
} \
else \
{ \
    ... do other different stuff ... \
    allocator.construct(place_to_insert_to, ASSIGNMENT_OBJECT); \
    ... etc ... \
} \
... more stuff again... \


iterator insert(the_type &object)
{
    LARGE_INSERT_MACRO(object)
}


iterator insert(the_type &&object)
{
    LARGE_INSERT_MACRO(std::move(object))
}


template<typename... Arguments> iterator emplace(Arguments... parameters)
{
    LARGE_INSERT_MACRO(parameters...)
}
```

Given the fact that the code before and after each insertion type is both necessary to the insertion, does not change between insertion types and cannot be factored away into two separate 'before and after' functions, how can this piece of (pseudo)code be changed so that it no longer uses macros?

As always, stay on the topic of changing macros to other code forms - please.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand why your macro is a macro in the first place. From what you have posted, it looks like you should be able to just replace `LARGE_INSERT_MACRO` with a (templated) function. What have you tried, and what was the problem?

Comment: better yet, a templated version of `insert()` which deduces the object to a universal reference. then there's just one code path to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to dump the large insert macro altogether and allow the wonder of universal reference deduction do all the work for you:

```
template<class TheType>
iterator insert(TheType&& object)  // object is deduced to be either r-value
                               // or l-value reference as required by context
{
    if(some_stuff) {
        ...
        return allocator.construct(place_to_insert_to, std::forward<TheType>(object));
    } else {
        ... and so on
    }
}
```

emplace without a template argument at the call site is only possible when it's a member function of a container which knows the type it contains. Otherwise you have to specify it. Again, note the use of universal reference deduction for perfect forwarding of arguments.

```
template<class TheType, typename... Arguments> 
iterator emplace(Arguments&&... parameters)
{
    return insert(TheType(std::forward<Arguments>(parameters)...));
}
```

Comment: If this answer scares the OP, a good way to absorb all of this is to have a look at some youtube video's of lectures by Scott Meyers on this subject (perfect forwarding).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So basically the emplace forwards on the call to the insert function. Unfortunately all allocator.construct functions I've tried don't perform copy elision with copy-constructed objects under the compilers I've used, so would I be right in assuming that there will be a copy generated from the object constructed by emplace? Or does std::forward do something with this? For performance reasons, this is somewhat important (with large classes which allocate/deallocate data).

Comment: If you're not getting copy elision it may well be because you've defined a destructor/copy constructor and not defined a move constructor, thus disabling move

Comment: But anyway, std::forward will do the right thing in all circumstances if it's forwarding a deduced universal reference. If performance is critical you really ought to read up on this. The latest effective c++ book covering c++11 and 14 is well worth buying.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the concept, having implemented it in colony now (plflib.org). You can remove the type specifier in the declaration of emplace, as it's shown to be within a container in the question.

For insert I think it would be helpful to quote the following in the answer:
"Don't let T&& fool you here - t is not an rvalue reference [2]. When it appears in a type-deducing context, T&& acquires a special meaning."
(http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/)
Until I read that I didn't understand what the 'template' for insert was doing.

Comment: @metamorphosis for the record, I thought your suggested edit was on the mark. Unfortunately I got there 6 hours too late and other people have rejected it on my behalf (I suspect they didn't fully follow the context of our conversation). Don't be discouraged.

Comment: No worries - what should I do at this point? You're welcome to update it yourself if that works.

Comment: sometimes that's the way it goes. dont worry. before long this question will be one of the other 400,000 questions gathering dust in a datacenter :-)

Comment: :) Thanks - btw, one final question, but only if you have time - 
I attempted to replace my prev macro situation with perfect forwarding and got it working, only to discover some performance regression with scalar types under GCC.
It wasn't emplace causing the problem, it was the combining insert(&the_type) and insert(&&the_type) into one function. 
Separating out the functions again reversed the issue.
There's not much point in me including code, it pretty much followed your example to the letter, but I wondered if you had any understanding of why this would be? Thanks-m

Comment: what are your optimiser settings? You'll want at least O2 i think.